# Redis Migration from a server where memory utilisation is almost 85%

Tags: redis

We have Redis server running on a machine with 16GB memory. The size of dataset of Redis is around 14GB. We are planning to migrate to a new instance with more memory. 
If we create replication from this server to new server, is it going to crash this master server?